# Pandas summing rows grouped by another column

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have attached dataset

```
 Time  podId  Batt (avg)  Temp (avg)
0   2019-10-07   9999         6.1   71.271053
1   2019-10-08   9999         6.0   71.208285
2   2019-10-09   9999         5.9   77.896628
3   2019-10-10   9999         5.8   78.709279
4   2019-10-11   9999         5.7   71.849283
59  2019-12-05   8888         5.5   76.548780
60  2019-12-06   8888         5.4   73.975295
61  2019-12-07   8888         5.3   76.209434
62  2019-12-08   8888         5.2   76.717481
63  2019-12-09   8888         5.1   70.433920
```

I imported it using- `batt2 =  pd.read_csv('battV2.csv')`

1. I need to determine when battery change occurs, i.e. when `Batt (avg)` increases from previous row. I am able to do this by using the 'diff' in this manner `batt2['Vdiff']=batt2['Batt (avg)'].diff(-1)`
2. Now for each `podId` I need to sum the `Vdiff` column between battery changes, i.e. between two negative `Vdiff` values
3. Also I need to average `Temp (avg)` over the same range
4. Count `Time` to determine the number of days between battery changes

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of steps involved:

### Import data

Be aware that I have changed your dataset a bit to provide a valid test case for your requirements (in your given dataset, `Batt_avg` never increases).

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = StringIO('''Time    podId  Batt_avg  Temp_avg
0   2019-10-07   9999         6.1   71.271053
1   2019-10-08   9999         6.0   71.208285
2   2019-10-09   9999         5.9   77.896628
3   2019-10-10   9999         5.8   78.709279
4   2019-10-11   9999         5.7   71.849283
5   2019-10-12   9999         6.0   71.208285
6   2019-10-13   9999         5.9   77.896628
7   2019-10-14   9999         5.8   78.709279
8   2019-10-15   9999         5.7   71.849283
59  2019-12-05   8888         5.5   76.548780
60  2019-12-06   8888         5.4   73.975295
61  2019-12-07   8888         5.3   76.209434
62  2019-12-08   8888         5.2   76.717481
63  2019-12-09   8888         5.1   70.433920''')
df = pd.read_csv(data,  delim_whitespace=True)
```

### Determine changes in battery voltage

As you have already found out, you can do this with `diff()`. I am not certain that the code you have given with `df.Batt_avg.diff(-1)` satisfies your requirement of: *"i.e. when Batt (avg) increases from previous row"*. Instead, for a given row, this shows how the value *will* change in the next row (multiplied by -1). If you need the negative change to the previous row, you can instead use `-df.Batt_avg.diff()`.

```
df['Batt_avg_diff'] = df.Batt_avg.diff(-1)
```

### Group data and apply the aggregation functions

You can express your grouping conditions as `df.podId.diff().fillna(0.0) != 0` for the podIds and `df.Batt_avg_diff.fillna(0.0) < 0` for the condition *"between battery changes, i.e. between two negative Vdiff values"* - either of these will trigger a new group. Use `cumsum()` on the triggers to create the groups. Then you can use `groupby()` to act on these groups and `transform()` to expand the results to the dimensions of the original dataframe.

```
df['group'] = ((df.podId.diff().fillna(0.0) != 0) | (df.Batt_avg_diff.fillna(0.0) < 0)).cumsum()
df['Batt_avg_diff_sum'] = df.Batt_avg_diff.groupby(df.group).transform('sum')
df['Temp_avg_mean'] = df.Temp_avg.groupby(df.group).transform('mean')
```

### Datetime calculations

For the final step, you need to first convert the string to datetime to allow date operations. Then you can use groupby operations to get the max and min in each group, and take the delta.

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
df['Time_days'] = df.Time.groupby(df.group).transform('max') - df.Time.groupby(df.group).transform('min')
```

---

Note: if you do not need or want the aggregate data in the original dataframe, just apply the functions directly (without transform):

```
df_group = pd.DataFrame()
df_group['Batt_avg_diff_sum'] = df.Batt_avg_diff.groupby(df.group).sum()
df_group['Temp_avg_mean'] = df.Temp_avg.groupby(df.group).mean()
df_group['Time_days'] = df.Time.groupby(df.group).max() - df.Time.groupby(df.group).min()
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the data. did not realize that I omitted the increases when I copied partial dataset.